# Django static files not working for other templates except index

Tags: python, html, django

I am developing an agency web app with django templates & static files. But **I am having trouble with loading static files on pages other than index**.
[Here's my folder heirarchy.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTCrc.png)
Again, I am having no problems loading static files on my index page.
Here's code of my additional page *services.html* (one I am trying to load static files on):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
  ...
  ...
  ...
{% endblock %}
```

My *base.html* is working totally fine with the homepage *index.html*.
I've included this on my *settings.py*

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

And, my *views.py* and *urls.py* files are working fine too.

Also my CSS file is correctly linked to the *services.html* file. I can tell this from the inspection.
[Here's the error list shown on inspection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxfot.png) Help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try replacing `STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` with 
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLVED.**
I was apparently not using Django HTML tags to link my static CSS/JS files.
So, I initialized static files on my *base.html* with *{% load static %}* and replaced links with *href="{% static 'assets/css/style.css' %}* format. This worked out. Remember that full path shouldn't be written i.e *{% static './static/assets/...' %}* instead just use *{% static 'assets/...' %}*.

Answer (score 0):

Your static files are stored in the `core` folder, so one way is to change the `settings.py` to :

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

The other way is to use `python manage.py collectstatic`. A new `staticfiles`  directory will be created which has folders for admin (the built-in admin has its own static files), `staticfiles.json`, and whatever directories are in your static folder.

Comment: Added that, cleared the cache, and restarted the server but sadly this still isn't working. Do I need to present anything else to make the question more clear?
EDIT: I also ran python manage.py collecstatic but no help.